# How do flat file content management systems create new .txt files?

Tags: php, content-management-system, flat-file, file-generation

I'm most interested in flatpress, since that is the one I'm currently working with. All i had to do with it was remove its 'read-only' status in windows 7. I have zero understanding of what 666 or 777 permissions are. If you have insight into other setups I wouldn't mind knowing that also. I'd really appreciate an indication of specific functions or lines of code that create the file. Would they have to be .txt files?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_permissions

Answer (score 1):

First thing to be able to create, read or delete files and folders the user that is running the PHP process must have permission to do so.

I recommend you to read and understand the concept of ACL´s - [Access Control List](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Access_control_list).

DOS had a simple and dangerous set of permissions, thats the main reason antiviruses exists: it was too easy to screw up DOS based systems, you won´t need a even a virus, with some time and use the system get corrupted, because actions of any program can compromise important parts of the system.

Depending on the OS, permissions scheme can be different, but let´s talk about Unix-like  simple permissions. Windows NT(any version after Windows XP) also implement ACL´s.

When you see 666, 777, 755, 644 this means:

```
0 --- no permission
1 --x execute
2 -w- write
3 -wx write and execute
4 r-- read
5 r-x read and execute
6 rw- read and write
7 rwx read, write and execute
```

And its a set for:  UGO = User, Group, Other, so 644 = User read and write, Group read, Other read.

So users can belong to groups and files and folders are properties of users and groups.

Also you can now imagine the concept of a super user, that can do anything, we can that "root" user on unix and "administrator" on windows liek systems.

Wikipedia is to straight, so I recommend the reading of [Understanding Permissions](http://www.elated.com/articles/understanding-permissions/)

Good study!